# Where are the youngest and oldest subduction zones in the world? Is the dip of the subducting slab proportional with the age of subduction?

Tags: tectonics, subduction, magmatism, plate, arc

I want to learn where the youngest subduction is in the world.   Where is the most recently started subduction zone? (The most recent place on Earth that arc magmatism has started)

And the oldest subduction zone?

Is the dip of the subducting slab proportional to the age of subduction?

Comment: for odest are you limited to active subduction zones, becasue we have extinct ones going back 2 Bya. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7406333/#:~:text=The%20relict%20collisional%20zone%20is,evidence%20of%20global%20plate%20tectonics.